# Cartesian relation $\preceq$ on $N\times N$ where $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)$ if $a\leq c$ and $b\leq d$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Studding for midterm. Lets define the Cartesian relation $\preceq$ on $N\times N$ where $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)$ if $a\leq c$ and $b\leq d$.

I'm trying to prove that the partially arranged set $\left(N \times N, \preceq\right)$ maintains the minimum condition.

As I understand $\left(A,\leq\right)$ is partially arranged set that maintains the minimum condition if for each $B\subseteq A$, $B\neq \varnothing$ contains a minimal number (at least one).

I understand the definition but how do I use it to prove the statement? Do I need to use induction for that?

Comment: The correct term is "well founded relation".

Comment: What you’re calling *partially arranged set* is actually a *partially **ordered** set* in English.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $A\subseteq\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ has no $\preceq$-minimal element. Then there must be a sequence $\big\langle\langle a_n,b_n\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$ such that $\langle a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\rangle\prec\langle a_n,b_n\rangle$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Now consider the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: What $\prec$ means?

Comment: @vesii: $\langle a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\rangle\prec\langle a_n,b_n\rangle$ means that $\langle a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\rangle\preceq\langle a_n,b_n\rangle$ and $\langle a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\rangle\ne\langle a_n,b_n\rangle$.

Comment: Also Is it correct to say that if $\langle a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\rangle\prec\langle a_n,b_n\rangle$ then $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ and then choose sequense like $a_n=n$ where it is not true?

Comment: @vesii: You can’t **choose** the sequence: you’re assuming that it exists, but that’s absolutely all that you know about it. And you want to use the fact that it’s strictly decreasing to get a contradiction, thereby showing that such a sequence does not in fact exist.

Comment: So what $a_{n+1}< a_n$ and $b_{n+1}<b_n$ give us?

Comment: @vesii: You know more than that: since $\langle a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\rangle\prec\langle a_n,b_n\rangle$, you know that either $a_{n+1}\color{red}{<}a_n$ and $b_{n+1}\le b_n$, or $a_{n+1}\le a_n$ and $b_{n+1}\color{red}{<}b_n$. At each step at least one of the coordinates must actually decrease.

Comment: So I guess we need to focus on one of them (because it does not matter which, it's the same for the second one). So let's assume that $a_{n+1}\color{red}{<}a_n$ and $b_{n+1}\le b_n$. I also guess it's should contradict $N$ being well ordered? But how? I'm sorry that I don't see it.

Comment: @vesii: You can’t simply focus on one of them, because it might happen that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for some $n$, but $b_{n+1}<b_n$ for other $n$. Let $$N_A=\{n\in\Bbb N:a_{n+1}<a_n\}$$ and $$N_B=\{n\in\Bbb N:b_{n+1}<b_n\}\,.$$ Show that at least one of these sets must be infinite and get a contradiction with the fact that $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Take $T \subseteq N \times N$. Define $T_a= \{a \in N : \exists b \  s.t. (a,b) \in T\}$. Since $N$ is well ordered exists $a_{min}=\min T_a$. Set $T_b=\{b \in B: (a_{min},b)\in T\}$.  Since $N$ is well ordered exists $b_{min}=\min T_b$. Then it is easy to see that $(a_{min},b_{min})$ is a minimal element of $T$

Comment: Why $(a_{min},b_{min})$ is minimum of $T$?

Comment: It is a minimal element because if you take $(c,d)\in N \times N$ then $a \leq c$ by definition of $T_a$. If $a=c$ then $b\leq d$ by definition of $T_b$. So $(c,d)$ is not smaller than $(a.b)$